# what would be the pythonic way to find out if a given date belongs to the current week?

Tags: python

I have strings in the "%Y%m%d" format (i.e., "20160511" for today, May 11, 2016). And need to find out programmatically (in python) if another date (let's say – "20160504" or "20160512") send as a parameter to the function belong to the current week (current being today the week started on Sunday, May 8, 2016 – let's assume it's an american way of the week, starting on Sunday, i.e., the first should return False, the second – True).

All ideas I came up with comes to calculating the date of that Sunday, and comparing the passed as a parameter to it, and then, if the day is in the future, that it's not after the Saturday of the current week, but it doesn't look elegant (or "pythonic") enough.

Comment: have you looked at the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module?

Comment: Use `datetime.datetime.today().weekday()` and then compare it minus and plus the current date based on `7` and see if it's inside. Pythonic-wise this will probably be something you can simply extend yourself on the `date time` library. Making your own library extensions is just as Pythonic as using existing ones :)

Comment: if you already have the date string for sunday, you can do something like `return int(string_for_sunday) - int(date_string) in range(7)` which ensures that the current string is within 7 days after Sunday. Definitely would be better to just use datetime's built-in date comparison as @User2910293 said.

Comment: For some countries/cultures/standards the week starts at Sunday, for some on Monday. Might be a localization implication too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `isodate` method for datetime objects:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('20160511','%Y%m%d').isocalendar()[1]
```

It will return the current week as an integer, so that you can compare two dates to see if they're part of the same week. Here is a function that would do that for two different dates:

```
import datetime

def same_week(date1, date2):
    d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date1,'%Y%m%d')
    d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date2,'%Y%m%d')
    return d1.isocalendar()[1] == d2.isocalendar()[1] \
              and d1.year == d2.year
```

To get the current day, use `datetime.datetime.today()`. So, rewriting the above function to do exactly what you're asking:

```
import datetime

def same_week(dateString):
    '''returns true if a dateString in %Y%m%d format is part of the current week'''
    d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateString,'%Y%m%d')
    d2 = datetime.datetime.today()
    return d1.isocalendar()[1] == d2.isocalendar()[1] \
              and d1.year == d2.year
```

Comment: Python questions always get the fastest answers lol. +1 tho. Nice example, didn't come to me instantly.

Comment: datetime.strptime('20160511','%Y%m%d').isocalendar()[1] returns 19. What do I do with it? What does it mean?

Comment: @User2910293 thank you :) Ya as someone else put it "beware SO ninjas"

Comment: @earlyadopter the 19 means it's the 19th week since the beginning of the year, I presume.

Comment: You'd want to compare the year as well, otherwise the same numbered week in two different years would compare equal, and that's not likely to be correct.

Comment: @earlyadopter happy to help :)